# Close DIV popup

Tags: javascript, css, html

we are showing a centered popup when a user clicks on a logo in a table. 
Everything works except ...

1. logos in the center of the screen(under where the popup is/will be) are not working, and
2. we need a close button on each the popup.

This is what we have so far:

```
<style type="text/css">
.main55{
position: fixed;
TOP:50%;
LEFT:50%;
width:400px;
height: 400px;
margin-top:-200px;
margin-left:-200px;

}
.menu0{ clear:both;

}
.menu0 div{
    cursor:pointer;
}

#main0 div{ 
display: none; 
}
#main0 div.block{ 
display: block;     
}
</style>


<script>
function setTab(m,n){
var tli=document.getElementById("menu"+m).getElementsByTagName("div");
var mli=document.getElementById("main"+m).getElementsByTagName("div");
for(i=0;i<tli.length;i++){
   tli[i].className=i==n?"hover":"";
   mli[i].style.display=i==n?"block":"none";
}
}
</script>


<!-----------------------table with LOGOS as menu items------------------------->

<div class="menu0" id="menu0">

<table  border=0 bordercolor=red width=900>

<td align=center valign=center width=180 height=200  background=frame55.gif   >
    <div onclick="setTab(0,1)">
    LOGO1
    </div>
</td>

<td align=center valign=center width=180 height=200 background=frame55.gif   >
    <div onclick="setTab(0,2)">
    LOGO2
    </div>
</td>

<td align=center valign=center width=180 height=200    background=frame55.gif   >
    <div onclick="setTab(0,3)">
    LOGO3
    </div>
</td>

<td align=center valign=center width=180 height=200    background=frame55.gif   >
    <div onclick="setTab(0,4)">
    LOGO4
    </div>
</td>

<td align=center valign=center width=180 height=200    background=frame55.gif   >
    <div onclick="setTab(0,5)">
    LOGO5  
    </div>
</td>
 </table>
</div>


<!-----------------DIVS WITH INFO TO POPUP--------------------->

<div class="main55" id="main0">

<div >
    <table BORDER=1 width=400 cellpadding=0 background=androidbk.gif>
    <td align=center>
     INFO1
    </td>
    </table>
</div>

<div >
    <table BORDER=1 width=400 cellpadding=0 background=androidbk.gif>
    <td align=center>
     INFO2
    </td>
    </table>
</div>

<div >
    <table BORDER=1 width=400 cellpadding=0 background=androidbk.gif>
    <td align=center>
     INFO3
    </td>
    </table>
</div>

<div >
    <table BORDER=1 width=400 cellpadding=0 background=androidbk.gif>
    <td align=center>
     INFO4
    </td>
    </table>
</div>

 <div >
    <table BORDER=1 width=400 cellpadding=0 background=androidbk.gif>
    <td align=center>
     INFO5
    </td>
    </table>
</div>

</DIV>
```

Comment: @Andy That was pretty brutal.. I've seen much worse

Comment: try to find any tool to help you write HTMl  code

Comment: @Andy No need to be so rude. Be a bit constructive instead.

Comment: Try to use Jquery and Jquery UI. That makes things like this a lot easier. For popups you can use Jquery UI dialog.

Answer (score 0):

you html is ver complex try this may be this is what you want?

```
 <p>May be you want this?  <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "showpopup();">here</a></p>
        <div id="light" class="white_content">This is the popup content. <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "hidepopup();">Close</a></div>
        <div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
```

JS

```
  function showpopup () {
       document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
       document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';
   }
   function hidepopup () {
       document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';
       document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none';
   }
```

CSS For Centered ligthbox

```
 .white_content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: 25%;
            left: 25%;
            width: 50%;
            height: 50%;
            padding: 16px;
            background-color: white;
            z-index:1002;
            overflow: auto;
        }
```

n CSS for black overlay for light box effects

```
.black_overlay{
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0%;
            left: 0%;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: black;
            z-index:1001;
            -moz-opacity: 0.8;
            opacity:.80;
            filter: alpha(opacity=80);
        }
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ObUpAgiH/1/edit?html,css,js)

Comment: you should include your code in your answer in addition to the link you have provided.